# google.visualization.DataTable(JSON.parse(datastring)) is not working

Tags: angularjs, json, google-visualization, plunker

I am using google charts to display some data on the screen and on some button click. The data is loading from webapi call.

To simplyfy the issue, I made the data hardcoded in function itself.

The issue is when I call

```
google.visualization.DataTable(JSON.parse(datastring))
```

Message: `Table has no columns.`

it is returning empty datatable. I also tried with arrayToDatable but no use.
I got error with arrayToDataTable. here is it.

```
Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys
```

I have create a plunker for it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/pctIqoCWi3LhqxlgdnqM?p=preview

Can anyone have a look and let me know whats wrong with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when creating `google.visualization.DataTable` directly from json,
the json must be in a specific format
see --> [Format of the Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

`google.visualization.arrayToDataTable` accepts an array of values, not objects...

```
[["ReportName","ReportTime"],["ABC",48],["XYZ",50]]
```

if you don't want to change the format of the results from the *webapi call*,
you'll need to transform the data for the chart

---

see following working snippet for an example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var datastring = '{"PerformanceData" : [{"ReportName":"ABC","ReportTime":"48"},{"ReportName":"XYZ","ReportTime":"50"}]}';
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(datastring);
    var chartData = [];

    // load chart data
    jsonData.PerformanceData.forEach(function (row, rowIndex) {
      // column headings
      var columns = Object.keys(row);
      if (rowIndex === 0) {
        chartData.push(columns);
      }

      // row values
      var chartRow = [];
      columns.forEach(function (column, colIndex) {
        var chartCell = row[column];
        if (colIndex > 0) {
          chartCell = parseFloat(chartCell);
        }
        chartRow.push(chartCell);
      });
      chartData.push(chartRow);
    });

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, { width: 400, height: 240 });
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

once the data table is built, use the [`group()` method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data) to aggregate the data

you can use one of the provided aggregation functions, or provide your own

```
google.visualization.data.avg
google.visualization.data.count
google.visualization.data.max
google.visualization.data.min
google.visualization.data.sum
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var datastring = '{"PerformanceData" : [{"ReportName":"ABC","ReportTime":"48"},{"ReportName":"XYZ","ReportTime":"50"},{"ReportName":"ABC","ReportTime":"48"},{"ReportName":"XYZ","ReportTime":"50"},{"ReportName":"ABC","ReportTime":"48"},{"ReportName":"XYZ","ReportTime":"50"},{"ReportName":"ABC","ReportTime":"48"},{"ReportName":"XYZ","ReportTime":"50"}]}';
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(datastring);
    var chartData = [];

    // load chart data
    jsonData.PerformanceData.forEach(function (row, rowIndex) {
      // column headings
      var columns = Object.keys(row);
      if (rowIndex === 0) {
        chartData.push(columns);
      }

      // row values
      var chartRow = [];
      columns.forEach(function (column, colIndex) {
        var chartCell = row[column];
        if (colIndex > 0) {
          chartCell = parseFloat(chartCell);
        }
        chartRow.push(chartCell);
      });
      chartData.push(chartRow);
    });

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

    // group data
    var dataGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
      data,  // data table
      [0],   // group by column
      [{     // aggregation column
        column: 1,
        type: 'number',
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
      }]
    );

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    // use group data to draw chart
    chart.draw(dataGroup, {
      pieSliceText: 'value',
      width: 400,
      height: 240
    });
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks... that helped... Can you also tell me to apply math formula at axis... by default everything is sum... I want to change it to avg, min, max